# Android How to programmatically select spinner value?

Tags: android, spinner

I need to select several spinners organized in a row one above the other programmatically.

I see spinnerId.setSelection(index), setSelected(true)?  Is there anything else I need to do to get these to show like a user selected them.  I want for there selection handlers to get invoked, just like if a user made selection.  do I need delay between them etc if they fetch data?

Comment: Is the data fetched from a data base or is it set from given array??

Answer (score 0):

use something like asynctask to refersh the ui

Take a look at asynctask which works on UI thread and used primarily for updating the values on the screen. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html